# Ruby dynamically create array

Tags: arrays, ruby, string

I have various test conditions and based on particular inputs I want to create what is an api body request that I can consume. There is one part of the request that I would like to build and based on that input return me a particular amount of additional blocks.

The method below has two 'blocks' currently hardcoded in:

```
def info(*value, *type)

#request build logic here

  return {
      'individual' => {
          'title' => 'Mr',
          'firstName' => 'Joe',
          'middleName' => '',
          'lastName' => 'Bloggs',
          'birthDate' => '2016-01-01',
          'incomeAmount' => 50,
          'emailAddress' => 'clear@gmail.com',

      },
      'blocks' => [
          {
              'value' => 400,
              'type' => 'car'
          },
          {
              'value' => 400,
              'type' => 'jug'
          }
      ]
  }
end
```

So based on the inputs I would like to create my 'blocks' e.g value = 100 , type = house so the block would just be that value in the format above.

With the idea being if I passed it 10 values / 10 types then I return all 10. I've attempted to call a another method that built my response but I'm struggling to get it to repeat based on the input

```
def block(value,type)
  "{
      'value' => #{value.to_i},
      'type' => #{type}
  },"
end
```

Comment: Show your failed attempts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're passing in a couple arrays of values and types, you can use the `zip` method to align them:

```
def info(values, types)
  blocks = values.zip(types).map do |value, type|
    {
      'value' => value.to_i,
      'type' => type
    }
  end

  {
    'individual' => {
      'title' => 'Mr',
      'firstName' => 'Joe',
      'middleName' => '',
      'lastName' => 'Bloggs',
      'birthDate' => '2016-01-01',
      'incomeAmount' => 50,
      'emailAddress' => 'clear@gmail.com'

    },
    'blocks' => blocks
  }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You're returning a hash, to insert into a larger hash, so there is no reason to try to produce a string containing a *serialized* hash. Just return a hash.

```
def block(value,type)
  {
      'value' => value.to_i,
      'type' => type
  }
end
```

If you want to turn an array of values and types into a series of hashes, you should use `map` on the array.